# javascript popup window remember last size and position

Tags: javascript, popup

I am opening pop-up window through JavaScript with resize option for end user. End user may resize pop-up window or change its default position by dragging it.

I have requirement of remembering last position and size of pop-up window when user closes the window.

At present I can keep last size of the pop-up window in *onbeforeunload* event using cookie. But still could not find last position of the window.

Am I missing something very obvious, or what I am doing is the correct way to do it.

Comment: afaik you can't set the position - this isn't something the browser has access to.

Comment: Luke: I can set position of the pop-up window through options available in window.open method. Problem here is to get last position of the window when it was closed by end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used cookie solution to remember position of last open window.

Answer (score 0):

The function window.open() returns a handler to the opened window.

```
var myWindow = window.open('some_url','some_name');
```

You could maybe then use the `myWindow` to obtain its position.

Make a try with `window.screenLeft/window.screenTop` on IE and `window.screenX/window.screenY` in other browsers to get the positon.

Hope this helps,
d.